# How do I manually create a dicitionary of series in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, series

I want to create a dictionary that has two series (manually). The series needs an index and a value. I don't know how to add the index. 
 This is what I want:

[image]

Here is what I have currently:

```
dict_full_profile = {}
dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'] = {}
dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'] = pd.Series([0.00428,0.184705,0.202432,0.300256,0.109422432,.177827355,0.0210740250])
dict_full_profile['MALE_EMP'] = pd.Series([0.017017233, 0.38140,0.300256,0.2749405,0.0263854])
```

How do I add the string indices?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like

```
dict_full_profile = {}
dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'] = {"Grade school":0.00428,"Some college" :0.184705, ...}
```

But if you want to keep your data in a pd.Series collection you can keep your code as it is and make a separate dictionary with the indexes.

```
indexes= {}
indexes['MALE_EDU'] = ["Grade school", "Some college", ...]
```

The order of the indexes in the new dictionary will be the same as in the series, so you can make something like dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'][indexes['MALE EDU'].indexOf("Grade school")] to get the corresponding value

Comment: I'm confused, with just these 4 lines of code, how do the indexes attach to the dictionary?

Comment: I added the reproduced code so you can test it (the indexes dictionary has the same structure as dict_full_profile but instead of series it contains a list of names, so when you get the index of a name you get the index of the corresponding value in dict_full_profile also).

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

dict_full_profile = {}
dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'] = {}
dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'] = pd.Series([0.00428,0.184705,0.202432,0.300256,0.109422432,.177827355,0.0210740250])
dict_full_profile['MALE_EMP'] = pd.Series([0.017017233, 0.38140,0.300256,0.2749405,0.0263854])

indexes= {}
indexes['MALE_EDU'] = ["Grade school", "Some college"]

index = indexes['MALE_EDU'].index("Grade school")
print(dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'][index])

index = indexes['MALE_EDU'].index("Some college")
print(dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'][index])
```

whenever you want some number from a series in your initial dictionary, you consult the second one to see what is the corresponding index

Answer (score 0):

To create a dictionary manually you need to create an empty dictionary as well as any embedded levels.  To create an index just use the syntax below (eg ,index[]).

```
dict_full_profile = {}
dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'] = {}
dict_full_profile['MALE_EDU'] = pd.Series([0.00428,0.184705,0.202432,0.300256,0.109422432,.177827355,0.0210740250],index=['G', 'F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'])
dict_full_profile['MALE_EMP'] = pd.Series([0.017017233, 0.38140,0.300256,0.2749405,0.0263854],index=['AA', 'AF', 'AE', 'AD', 'AC'])
```